# Evaluating swaptions with negative interest rates

Tags: options, quantlib, swaption

Does anyone know if it is possible to evaluate swaptions with negative interest rates with Quantlib?

```
    blackEngine = ql.BlackSwaptionEngine(discountingTermStructure, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(vol)))
    swaption.setPricingEngine(blackEngine)
    swaptionnpv = swaption.NPV()
```

My vol value is an interpolated value from a volatility matrix which is equal to 0.34.

```
RuntimeError: forward + displacement (-0.00128788 + 0) must be positive
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi and welcome. Would you please add more details to your question, esp. the software (I guess it's QuantLib?) and the calling code? A pure guess: You use lognormal vols with negative rates?

Comment: Edited, thank you.

Comment: It's customary to use the bachelier [normal](https://rkapl123.github.io/QLAnnotatedSource/de/dd1/class_quant_lib_1_1_bachelier_swaption_engine.html) model because the lognormal assumption of Black doesn't allow for negative values.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example on pricing the the Bachelier model (Normal vols):

```
import QuantLib as ql

yts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(2, ql.TARGET(), 0.05, ql.Actual360()))

calendar = ql.TARGET()
today = ql.Date().todaysDate()
exerciseDate = calendar.advance(today, ql.Period('5y'))
exercise = ql.EuropeanExercise(exerciseDate)
swap = ql.MakeVanillaSwap(ql.Period('5y'), ql.Euribor6M(yts), 0.05, ql.Period('5y'))
swaption = ql.Swaption(swap, exercise)


bachelierEngine = ql.BachelierSwaptionEngine(yts, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(0.0055)))
swaption.setPricingEngine(bachelierEngine)
swaption.NPV()
```